# Passing CVarArg in inner func

Tags: swift, string

I need a wrapper for default func `String.init(format: String, arguments: CVarArg...)` -> `func custom(someParam: String, arguments: CVarArg...)`

But when I tested it, I have found, that passed arguments were wrapped in `Array` and can't be used in `init(format:)` bcs of different format - `Array<CVarArg>` instead of queue `arg1, arg2, ...`

Is there any way to direct transfer passed CVarArg value to inner func?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a `String` initialiser with the function signature `init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])`, so you can simply pass your arguments to that one.

```
func custom(someParam: String, arguments: CVarArg...) {
    String(format: someParam, arguments: arguments)
}
```

Compiles just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't event expect different behavior between same function signature, except only one difference - omitted argument label **arguments** (confused, why this argument label difference even exist )